# Multiple POST requests with RxJava

Tags: kotlin, post, retrofit, rx-java, concatenation

I have a list of Books.

```
open class Book(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String? = null,
    var title: String? = null,
    var author: String? = null
): RealmObject()
```

While for-looping, I filter some books and create an Observable with filtered ones. I add each observable to an array.

```
val listInserts = ArrayList<Observable<Book>>()
for loop(..) {
  if (localBook condition) {
    val postObservable = networkApiAdapter.insert(localBook)
    listInserts.add(postObservable)
  }
}
```

I merge (or concat) the observables hoping for some sequential POST requests.

```
        Observable.concat(listInserts)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { s ->
                    println(s)
                },
                { err ->
                    println(err)
                },
                { println("onComplete") }
            )
```

Always **only one POST request** is received at my MongoDb+Flask server and I also get this error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 4 path $
```

networkApiAdapter functions, **Retrofit**:

```
class NetworkAPIAdapter private constructor() {
    fun insert(dto: Book): Observable<Book> {
        println(dto.toString())
        return bookService.insert(dto.title!!, dto.author!!)
    }

    interface BooksService {
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST(URL_ORDERS_ALL)
        fun insert(
            @Field("title") title: String,
            @Field("author") author: String
        ): Observable<Book>
    }
}
```

Any help would be welcomed. I don't know how to do multiples requests. I have tried many solutions with zip, repeatUntil, flatMap, but none worked.

After solving this, I have to delete all local books and do a GET request. All somehow working using RxJava.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `BooksService.insert` is defined as a `POST` request that expects a response from server in form of a `Book` JSON string (i.e. `Observable<Book>`). I think that is not what your server returns after the `POST` request goes through. Check what your `POST` request returns, I think it returns some `Int` (probably a response status) instead of a `Book`, which would explain your error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 4 path $
```

If that is the case, your concatenated Observable will terminate as soon as the error is thrown, i.e. right after your first `POST` request, therefore the remaining requests will not be executed.

If my assumptions were right, change your service to:

```
interface BooksService {
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST(URL_ORDERS_ALL)
        fun insert(
            @Field("title") title: String,
            @Field("author") author: String
        ): Observable<Int>
    }
```

Also, if you want your other requests to execute even if the previous throws an error, do:

```
val postObservable = networkApiAdapter.insert(localBook).onErrorReturn(_ -> SOME_INT_FLAG)
```

**UPDATE**

To execute your required logic after all the `POST` requests have been sent, try:

```
    Observable.concat(listInserts)
        // complete this observable after all POST requests have been sent
        // not that it does not necesarily mean that all responses were 200, you should implement yourself what happens to items that were not successfully `POST`ed
        .take(listInserts.size)
        .doOnComplete { 
            // called when this observable completes, i.e. when all POST requests have been sent
            executeFinalActions()
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { s->
                println(s)
            },
            { err ->
                println(err)
            },
            { println("onComplete") }
        )
```

And implement the `executeFinalActions()` function:

```
private fun executeFinalActions() {
    realm.executeTransaction(Realm::deleteAll)
    networkApiAdapter.fetchAll()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { books ->
                // todo: store books
            },
            { err ->
                println(err)
            }
        )
}
```

PS: you may want to have a look what `Observable.take()` does: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html

Comment: Do you also know how to call this function after all POSTs return 200? 
`realm.executeTransaction(Realm::deleteAll)`
and afterwards this GET request which returns an Observable<List<Book>>?
`networkApiAdapter.fetchAll()`
So, a sequential flow: POSTs, deleteAll, fetchAll.

Comment: Thank you!  You saved me a lot of time.